# Confused about user profiles in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, profile

I'm very confused about the whole user profile thing in drupal, hope someone can help me out here since I haven't found a clear answer anywhere else.

For starters, where do you set up custom fields for users, is it under 'admin/user/profile' or under 'admin/content/node-type/profile' (with the content_profile Module installed)? I have tried both but only fields that were added in the 'default' user/profile section and set to appear on the **registration** page actually showed up there. Is it ok to use both or should I stick to using only one?

Once the user is logged in and I go to edit the profile, eg. 'user/1/edit/' no other fields apart from the default ones show up in the resulting form. I can't really imagine that I have to add them manually in the 'themename_user_profile_form' hook?

Would be cool if someone could help me out here or point me to a resource where this is covered.

**Edit:**
This turned out being the hint I was looking for: http://drupal.org/node/517094 The snipped posted there isn't quite right, what I did was add a new module that hooks into edit_profile_user:

```
function edit_profile_user ( $op, &$edit, &$account, $category = null )
{
    global $user;
    switch ( $op )
    {
        case 'form':
            return profile_form_profile( $edit, $user, 'Name of the Category' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit; could you go into more detail about the full process including the theme changes, perhaps in a linked to page?

Comment: I added the above code to one of my modules and it didn't work. I assume there is more to it than that. Can you please list all your steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lovely page about [extending user account information](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/profile) in the docs.

Comment: Thanks, but I already went through that. As I said, I can add fields to the registration process using the method described just fine but not on the edit page. As a bonus, profile_load_profile( $user ); does not load the custom fields into the $user object..

Comment: Ok, I looked further and finally started getting somewhere. Turns out you have to add your own module that will hook into 'edit_profile_user' where you then have to load profile_form_profile() of the section you added which you can then edit with your 'themname_user_profile_form'. What a hassle..

Comment: @c_ham - it is trivial to add additional flds to a user. it is more difficult to allow different sets of flds for different user roles and also have ability to tag the users with different taxonomy terms. This set of docs does not address it.    Jan - did you solve this? I am trying to figure out how to set up different profiles for different user roles...for me , the additional twist is that accounts can be created programatically, via admin interface or by users themselves...